# Webbrowser Control DocumentText not updated but Document.Body.InnerHtml does

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I'm building an html editor using the webbrowser control and I'm discovering that while I can update the living html document and access tags accordingly none of the updates appear in the WebBrowser control DocumentText, which is what I use to save the document and to intialize a textbox. So I can see the changes made in the browser but I can't save them or load them into a textbox!

So what gives with this problem? The DOM elements appear to update but the DocumentText method doesn't update or grab what's being added to the page. The only solution I can see is grabing all the DOM elements and then parsing them back together in a string, that really sucks!

Appreciate any help, thx

Comment: Have you tried using Update or Refresh? And what are the effects?  How are you settings/modifying the HtmlDocument?

Comment: You might want to post the relevant part(s) of your code.

Comment: No update or refresh would not work, the actual view from the browser is fine, its only the DocumentText that doesn't update, but the webpage does update within the browser!

Comment: this is the code I'm using to update the html: webPage.Document.Body.InnerHtml = "<p>Some Text</p>"

Comment: There is no solution to this problem and safe to say that while you can use the control to render html in real time, as it works today, it can never really be used as a sophisticated editor on its own.